# Authenticate with sfguarduser without http login

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I'm trying to develop a webservice in a symfony based application, we are using a sfguarduser plugin, and i want to get user credentials authenticated in a single shot request to check user permissions and then execute webservice action, is there any way to perform login action without html form login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your action do the following:

```
$this->getUser()->signin($sfGuardUserObject);
```

Which you must call with an object of sfGuardUser. You could put this code in a preExecute() method of the module, to check on each request.

I did something similar when I was doing an "activate account" action. An email with a token is sent after account creating, it contains a link back to the site. A token is sent in the URL and matched in the route to the action. The action then checks if a user has that token and then logs the user in. This is what I did:

```
public function executeActivate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  // if token is not present, forward to 404
  $this->forward404Unless($request->getParameter('token'), 'page', 'index');

  $this->profile = sfGuardUserProfilePeer::activateProfileByToken($request->getParameter('token'));

  // if someone was activated, return the mobile activation form and success page
  if (!$this->profile)
  {
    $this->redirect404();
  }

  // sign the user in
  $this->getUser()->signin($this->profile->getsfGuardUser());

  // set the $user variable for the template
  $this->user = $this->profile->getsfGuardUser();

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good answer. BTW, `sfAction::forward404If` is a handy method if you don't know about it.

Comment: sorry for all this time without answering, was a little bit busy, nowadays dont remember what i did, but i ll mark your answer as the right one, because sounds legit, thank you very much for your answer :-)